# prediction with string similarity

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data

Assume we have an input of an email and we want to predict if it is spam or not spam.

Without being a statistician, i would think one of the predictors takes the subject of the input email and compares it to known spam email subjects and generate a lev distance.  To me this would be a strong predictor of a spam email. Another predictor would take the body and compare it to known spam email bodies generating another lev score. We would then take both predictors as part of a logistic regression model to generate probability of spam or not spam for a given input email. Does this seem like a good approach? Could someone point me to some papers or search terms to learn more about this approach or a better approach? I'm not specifically interested in spam filtering but rather using past string based observations with known outcomes to predict future unknown outcomes by comparing strings on how similar they are.

Comment: After some more searching, i think what i'm looking for is something like this http://stevenloria.com/how-to-build-a-text-classification-system-with-python-and-textblob/